# Invoke Download from html5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to download the current audio in my html5 audio tag using javascript.
Solutions like add a link with same file address not working for me because i have parts of my application that i've load Base64 files on the audio tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you tried a blob url

Comment: I'll add an html link and set it `src=audio.src` and trigger the download. this works both link and base64 object.

Thanks.